# I want to move my Left nav bar menu <div> to Top when the screen size is 800px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i reduce my screen to 800px then left nav will hide it will appear on the top of the page with dropdown

Comment: Without code we cannot help you.

Comment: Yes without code no one will help you.

Comment: use [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a media query for this and set the width of the media query to 800px

for example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #leftmenu {
        #css to put menu at top
    }
}
```